# why does googletest require -lpthread option?

Tags: c++, linux, pthreads, googletest

I've been told to execute `g++ test.cpp -lgtest -lpthread` to generate the unittest.
I am wondering why `googletest` requires `-lpthread` library. Since my code doesn't include anything from the `pthread` library, is this necessary for `googletest` to run appropriately?

Comment: It is (generally) not correct either way. For pthread support one should compile and link with `-pthread` instead of `-lpthread`. Not on every platform is `-lpthread` sufficient.

Comment: If it works without the flag, then you likely don't need it. If it doesn't work, the error message will tell you more.

Comment: I presume Google Test needs pthread because (TDD-style) unit tests ought to be able to be run in parallel.

Answer (score 1):

As for the manuals [1](http://google.github.io/googletest/pkgconfig.html), [2](https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/github.com/google/googletest/+/refs/tags/release-1.8.0/googletest/#build)

> GoogleTest might also require `-pthread` in the compiling step.

It requires `pthread` if it's built without the option `gtest_disable_pthreads` set to `ON`.

Usage of `-lpthread` is wrong since it's only a linker flag, it doesn't enable required compiler options for multi-threaded applications.